# marginnote: missing number, treated as zero

Tags: marginnote

Compiling the following - not so minimal - example with LuaLaTeX gives me a `Missing number, treated as zero` error.

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sansmath,scale=0.88]{MyriadPro}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\[ c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \marginnote{foo $x$ bar} \]
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the document compiles fine if I remove *any* package, font command, or even option (besides `no-math`, which is necessary for `MyriadPro`). On top of that, the file also compiles fine if I remove the inline equation from `\marginnote`, or if I set the `\marginfont` to `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, or anything above `\large`. Draft mode also makes it work...

I fear that the problem is badly reproducible because of the font packages, but I have no idea where to even start looking for the problem.

---

**Edit:** The full error message from the log file:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
l
l.257 \@tempcnta=l
                eft_boundary\relax\MT@dofont@function
<argument> ...@ex@factor@ relax }MT@lua {microtype.do_font()}

use_i:nn #1#2->#1

MT@set@ex@codes ...T@ex@factor }MT@reset@ef@codes 
                                                  MT@expandfont MT@nonselect...

MT@maybe@do ...#1}csname MT@set@#1@codesendcsname 
                                                  else MT@vinfo {... No @nam...

MT@setupfont ...@line }MT@protrusion MT@expansion 
                                                  MT@noligatures MT@register...

pickup@font ...ster@subst@font fi fi MT@setupfont 
                                                  endgroup 
getanddefine@fonts ...size endcsname }pickup@font 
                                                  let textfont@name font@nam...

mv@normal ...define@fonts {8}T1/MyriadPro-OsF/m/n 
                                                  install@mathalphabet maths...

glb@settings ... csname mv@math@version endcsname 
                                                  globaldefs @ne math@fonts ...

check@mathfonts ...rsize f@size else glb@settings 
                                                  init@restore@glb@settings ...

<everymath> check@mathfonts 
                the everymath 
<to be read again> 
x
<argument> ...arginnote strut hspace {z@ }ignorespaces foo $x
                                                  $ barendgraf vss }vss }
rlap #1->hb@xt@ z@ {#1
                      hss }
<argument> ...z@ }ignorespaces foo $x$ barendgraf vss }vss }}
                                                  else llap {vbox toz@ {kern...

mn@zbox #1->bgroup setbox @tempboxa vbox {#1
                                            }ht @tempboxa ht strutbox dp @te...

@mn@@@marginnote ...fi fi kern marginparsep }fi }}
                                                  endgroup 
@mn@@marginnote ...n@@@marginnote [{#1}]{#2}[{#3}]
                                                  fi 
<to be read again> 
]
l.16 ...\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \marginnote{foo $x$ bar} \]

?
```

Comment: I don't have the fonts so can't run it but stick `\errorcontextlines=10000` on the first line, then post the full error message from the log, from `!` to `?` in a `{}` code block so line ends preserved

Comment: Loading the `MyriadPro` package along with `fontspec` seems dubious to begin with.

Comment: @egreg Hence the `sansmath` option. As far as I understood the documentation, this should provide a mathversion sans but not modify other fonts. However, I just double checked and the sans-serif text font *is* changed. And using `onlymath` together with `sansmath` results in another error...